# specifying specific value options for sql column

Tags: sql, oracle

If I have a column - for example, call it `lettergrade`.

Besides specifying that it is `CHAR(1)`, is there anyway to constrain it to be A, B, C, D, or E at creation?

Comment: Yes, you could do that with a `DEFAULT` constraint.  The syntax however is not consistent between vendors (Oracle, MySQL, etc).  Which one are you working with?

Comment: oracle sql, it is just for a class, in the notes of the lettergrade column it says it must be A,B,C,D, or E

Comment: that only sets one default value, i want to set an array of possible values that it can be, can that be checked at insertion?

Comment: I understand what you want: `IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')`.  Though, I'd use an additional table, and setup a foreign key constraint

Answer (score 5):

```
alter table your_table_name add (
  constraint grade_constraint
  check (lettergrade in ('A','B','C','D','E')));
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, in this case, a letter grade, I think a check constraint makes more sense.  A foreign key makes more sense in the case where you're going to need to change the allowable valid values on a regular basis.  In the case of a letter grade, the possibilities of A,B,C,D, or E are not likely to change.  Also, since check constraint makes more sense in this case, consider that it's also less overhead than a foreign key constraint, which will carry additional locking overhead.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways to handle this. The best might be with a foreign key constraint as that will allow you to change the acceptable values easily. A check constraint could also work depending on your RDBMS but will likely be less flexible.